# How to add multiple image into EditText using spannable or any other way?

Tags: image, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder

I am creating a note taking app, I have done text section and its working properly. Also database working properly. But I want to add image in the EditText. When user add an image, it will place at the EditText cursor position and this task will happen for multiple image. And save the EditText entities (text and image) in SQL Lite database.

Please help someone to do this job. Thank you.

I have tried this job in onActivityResult , but image are not showing

```
if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
    Uri imageUri= data.getData();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        final ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        Spannable span = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText().toString()+"\n");
        span.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        editText.append(span, 0, ("\n").length());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing zero characters when you do the following:

```
span.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

You will need to replace at least one character. Since you are inserting an *ImageSpan*, you will need to add at least one character to replace.

```
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
Editable editable = editText.getText();
// Insert a single space to replace.
editable = editable.insert(0, " ");
editable.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setText(editable);
```

Comment: Thanks, image adding task is solved. But when I save this EditText entities into sql lite database, no image are showing.

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: This is the question, I need the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72721356/how-to-save-imagespan-with-text-into-sql-lite-database