# How to Save ImageSpan with text into SQL Lite Database?

Tags: spannablestring, spannable, spannablestringbuilder, imagespan, android-spannable

I have implemented image in EditEtxt. Its working fine. I want to save the whole editText entities(Text & image) in sql lite database. When i save it to sql only text are showing not images. I also tried with `Html.toHtml` and `Html.fromHtml`. Its also not working.

This bunch of code to add image in editText:

```
            Uri imageUri= data.getData();
            InputStream inputStream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
           
            final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            final ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

            SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText()+".\n");
            span.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, (".\n").length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            editText.append(span, 0, (".\n").length());
```

To save in databse

```
                    String textWithImage= Html.toHtml(editText.getText());
                        Note note = new Note(textWithImage);
                        Databse databse= new Databse(this);
                        databse.insertInDB(note);
```

Fetch data from database

```
databse= new Databse(this);
    note= databse.getSingleNote(noteId);
    String text= note.getNoteText();
    editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Please help someone to do this task. Thank you.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `Html.toHtml(editText.getText())` produces as HTML. What would the source for the image tag be?

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying with Html, I didn't know it it works or not. Is there any other procedures to solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to save the URI into the database. Your approach with `Html.toHtml()` is valid, but you are not linking the Uri to the *ImageSpan* and are, probably, getting a `null` in the `src` attribute. Try another *ImageSpan* constructor:

[ImageSpan (Drawable drawable,
String source,
int verticalAlignment)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan#ImageSpan(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

where `source` is your Uri string.

Now when you call `Html.toHtml()`, the `src` attribute of the `img` tag will contain the URI. To interpret the `src` attribute, you will need to supply an [Html.ImageGetter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter) which will look something like this:

```
// This function is used by HtmlCompate.fromHtml to retrieve drawables for the img tag.
override fun getDrawable(source: String?): Drawable {
    val uri = Uri.parse(source)
    val stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
    val drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
    return drawable
}
```

Here, source is the URI for your drawable. (This is Kotlin, but it is close enough to the Java to understand.)

This will not store your bitmap drawable in the database and assumes that the drawable is at the same URI when the data is read from the database.

Comment: I am curious why this answer was un-accepted.